# How to fix this error in console when I create a new laravel project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

I never encounter this error before now I'm stucked with it, can someone helped how to fix these?

It returns this red background error

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Heres the full errors:
[image]

My php version is `7.2.0`. Im using windows10. I already create a laravelv6 project before. I dont why I receive the error above. someone help?
[image]

Comment: This seems to need PHP version 7.2.5 , it's possible at some point a dependency of a dependency was updated to require `css-selector v5` which requires that PHP version. You could try to manually require a fixed laravel version (e.g. 6.0) instead of autmatically installing the latest but I suggest updating you PHP version instead

Comment: as the errors suggest your php version is lower than the required. upgrade the php version.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon okay2 I got it. thanks bdw guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be what the error message says:

> symfony/css-selector v5.0.0 **requies php ^7.2.5** -> your PHP version
>   (**7.2.0**) does not satisfy that requirement.

Solution: Update your PHP with the latest version

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing a new Laravel project I imagine it is a version 6 project. Laravel 6 requires at least PHP 7.2 per their documentation. Not sure what system you're installing it on but it needs at least php 7.2. [See the full docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/installation#server-requirements).

[image: Laravel installation requirements]

Comment: my php version is `7.2.0`, I check it using `php -v`

Comment: The packages you're installing require PHP 7.2.9 and you have 7.2.0, which I think is dumb but that that's causing it to fail but that's the issue. You gotta update your PHP version to at least 7.2.9.

Comment: now doing it. i dont read the console carefully. sorry little mistake :)